# DiscordJS: replace only specific part of JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I am making a bot on discord.JS that creates a JSON database with a few values.
How do I make it, so instead of completely overwriting the whole JSON, the code just edits the specified object?

```js
if (message.content.startsWith("/requestdeposit")){
             
             let moneyrequest = message.content.split(" ");
                 
             moneyrequest.shift();
     
             moneyrequest = moneyrequest.join(" ");
     var num69 = moneyrequest;
             if(isNaN(num69)){
             
                 message.channel.send("You did not enter a valid number.")
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     
                     

                      requester = message.author.id;
                      
                      let link = require('./money.json')
                     var userid1 = "";
                     userid1 = message.author.id;
                     
                   link = {[userid1]: {
                          name: `${message.author.username}`,
                          balance: `${moneyrequest}`
                        }
                     }
                       
                      
                     const stringifiedrequest = JSON.stringify(link, null, 4,'\t');
                     
                     
                       

                     fs.writeFile('money.json', stringifiedrequest, (err) => {
                         if (err) {
                             throw err;
                         }
                         console.log("JSON data is saved.");
                     });
                 }
                  }
```

Example JSON:

```
{
"427861168284106762": {
    "name": "woodendoors7",
    "balance": "1"
}}
```

How can I make it so when the user runs the command, it only overwrites the object with their user ID (replaces "name" and "balance") but keeps every other part of the JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overwriting the JSON Object with

```
link = {[userid1]: {
                      name: `${message.author.username}`,
                      balance: `${moneyrequest}`
                    }
                 }
```

you can assign it

```
link[userid]: {...}
```